# Using static methods within post save middleware

Tags: node.js, mongoose, static-methods

I have a static method to exec a find() and add Campaign data to Redis when the app starts.

```
CampaignSchema.statics.activeCampaignsToRedis = function () {
    this
        .find()
        .where('active').equals(true)
  ...
};
```

I'd like to add a post save hook that would rerun the static method to update the data in Redis whenever a new Campaign is added or modified.

```
CampaignSchema.post('save', function (next) {
  // call CampaignSchema.statics.activeCampaignsToRedis();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your post-save middleware callback receives the saved document as its one parameter, not a next function.  From there you can access the doc's model via its (undocumented) `constructor` property.

So you could write your middleware function as:

```
CampaignSchema.post('save', function (doc) {
  doc.constructor.activeCampaignsToRedis();
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you much. Always forget about the damned constructor :)

Comment: This will also work for any other Document middleware such as `init`, `validate`, and `remove`.